# Up Arrow Key does not work on Pavilion x360

Tags: keyboard

my up key on my Pavilion x360 is not working. I plugged in a keyboard to my laptop and plugged it out and then the up key stopped working. Could anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this might be just a coincidence and it physically broke or your driver got messed up, just go to
Controll Panel > Device Manager - uninstall all keyboards - search for new drivers. This should solve it.